# Garbled Korean and Chinese characters in ggplot2 axes

Tags: r, ggplot2, character-encoding

I can't get ggplot2 to render Korean and Chinese characters in the axes correctly, as you can see below:

[image: Axes with garbled Korean and Chinese characters]

The item at the top is in Korean while the 5th from the bottom contains Chinese characters.

You can reproduce the "plot" with the code below:

```
top_artists <- structure(
  list(
    artist = c("John Mayer", "Jorge Drexler", "Netsky", 
               "Daft Punk", "Joe Satriani", "Steve Vai", "Zero 7", "Pendulum", 
               "Jamie Cullum", "소녀시대", "Coldplay", "Killswitch Engage", 
               "Andy McKee", "toe", "Bombay Bicycle Club", "Roadrunner United", 
               "Kaskade", "Robot Science", "HOME MADE 家族", "Opeth"),
    genre = c("singer-songwriter", "singer-songwriter", "drum and bass",
              "electronic", "guitar virtuoso", "guitar virtuoso",
              "chillout", "drum and bass", "jazz", "k-pop", 
              "rock", "metalcore", "acoustic", "post-rock", "indie", "metal", 
              "house", "electronic", "hip-hop", "progressive metal"),
    n = c(760L, 603L, 564L, 428L, 418L, 417L, 417L,
          410L, 407L, 402L, 387L, 385L, 319L, 303L,
          292L, 289L, 275L, 257L, 256L, 244L)),
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
  row.names = c(NA, -20L),
  .Names = c("artist", "genre", "n"))

ggplot(top_artists, aes(artist, n)) + coord_flip()
```

I realize that I should have geoms to actually show the data but I figured I'd go as minimal as possible. The issue persists in the full blown plot with geoms, scales, and theme settings, etc...

And here is my sessionInfo:

```
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.5 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] viridis_0.3.4       scales_0.4.0        hrbrmisc_0.0.0.9002 zoo_1.7-13          streamgraph_0.8.1  
[6] ggplot2_2.1.0       lubridate_1.5.6     tidyr_0.5.1         dplyr_0.5.0        

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.5      rstudioapi_0.6   magrittr_1.5     munsell_0.4.3    xtable_1.8-2    
 [6] colorspace_1.2-6 lattice_0.20-33  R6_2.1.2         stringr_1.0.0    plyr_1.8.4      
[11] tools_3.3.0      xts_0.9-7        grid_3.3.0       gtable_0.2.0     miniUI_0.1.1    
[16] DBI_0.4-1        htmltools_0.3.5  lazyeval_0.2.0   assertthat_0.1   digest_0.6.9    
[21] tibble_1.0       gridExtra_2.2.1  shiny_0.13.2     formatR_1.4      htmlwidgets_0.6 
[26] mime_0.4         memoise_1.0.0    labeling_0.3     stringi_1.1.1    httpuv_1.3.3
```

Comment: Have you tried installing Korean/Chinese language support on your system? I tested on Linux just now and it worked without any modification.

Comment: I will try to do that. The characters are displayed correctly in the R console, the code, and in this post in Safari.

Comment: No success installed Korean and Chinese and the labels are still garbled.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the issue was related to the font that the default ggplot2 theme uses on MacOS which does not support Korean/Japanese.

To fix it I had to manually set the font to "HiraginoSans-W3".

`theme(axis.title = element_text(font = "HiraginoSans-W3"))`